# glViewport inside loop cause smaller view port

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I've a simple OpenGL program running on macOS:

```
glUseProgram(program);
glViewport(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);
glClearColor(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f, 1.0f);

// Rendering Loop
while (glfwWindowShouldClose(mWindow) == false) {
    if (glfwGetKey(mWindow, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS) {
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(mWindow, true);
    }

    // why can't view port here?
    glViewport(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);

    // Background Fill Color
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    // Flip Buffers and Draw
    glfwSwapBuffers(mWindow);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

If I comment out the `glViewport` call inside the loop, it works well, the triangle is rendered in the center of the window, but if I uncomment it, the triangle shows in the left bottom corner of the window.

Below is my shader and vertex data code:

```
const int mWidth = 1280;
const int mHeight = 800;
auto mWindow = glfwCreateWindow(mWidth, mHeight, "OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);

const GLchar* vertex_shader_src =
    "#version 330 core\n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "    gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
    "}";

const GLchar* fragment_shader_src =
    "#version 330 core\n"
    "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "    FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
    "}";

GLfloat vertices[] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f
};

GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

GLuint vbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float),
                      (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

As [@httpdigest commented](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53538648/3077508#comment93945404_53538648), it is because macOS has 2x larger frame buffer size, if I query it with `glfwGetFramebufferSize` and use it as view port size, it works well!